# Parsing a config file in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a config file that's sorted like so

```
Setting:
  setting_name: Foo1 
  age: 12
  etc.....
Setting:
  setting_name: Foo2
  age: 12
  etc....
```

I have tried using this, but I realize it won't work, but I do not know another way

```
Setting_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(Classes.StaticData.Entities_Resource_Path);
string[] fileNames = null;

            foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
            }

            foreach (string filename in fileNames)
            {
                if (filename.Contains(".cfg"))
                {
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("Setting"))
                        {
                            Setting_Dictionary.Add(line.Split(':')[0].TrimStart(), line.Split(':')[1].TrimStart());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I realize this approach is fine if the file was only setup as

```
setting: asdf
setting: fdsa
setting: qwerty
```

But I need help with how this config is setup. Thanks!

Comment: Use JSON which gives you more functionality

Comment: Is the example of the config file absolutely correct or have you removed parts for brevity? It looks almost like JSON except it's missing brackets and quotation marks.

Comment: Why not use a standard format like JSON, YAML, XML, INI, or any of the dozens of other standardized formats instead of rolling your own?

Comment: It does look like json indeed. But no, this is exactly how the entire file is done. I removed a couple hundred lines, but its exactly how I have it here. One config has 2775 lines.. of the repeating pattern I put above. It's crazy.

Comment: Then your question is a little broad. Saying "this code doesn't work" without specifying exactly what's wrong and what you've tried to fix it is essentially the same as saying "please write the whole thing for me".

Comment: That said as a hint, read your config file line by line and think about what is being added to your `Settings_Dictionary`. If the line looks like `Settings:`, what would your split code do? If the line doesn't contain the word settings like `age: 12` what does your split code do?